# Unable to install helm chart on private Google Kubernetes Engine (timeout error)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have created a private cluster in gke with the follwoing

```
gcloud container clusters create private-cluster-0 \
--create-subnetwork name=my-subnet-0 \
--enable-master-authorized-networks \
--enable-ip-alias \
--enable-private-nodes \
--enable-private-endpoint \
--master-ipv4-cidr 172.16.0.32/28 \
--zone us-central1-a
```

Then I did

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone us-central1-a private-cluster-0
```

I was trying to install a helm chart from my local machine but I got the following error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://172.16.0.34/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.16.0.34:443: i/o timeout
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error.
How to deploy an helm chart from a local machine to a private cluster in gke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a private cluster and trying to install helm from local machine.
This won't work because 172.16.0.0/12 range is non-routable, your PC is looking for the cluster in your own LAN.

You can find information on accessing private GKE clusters on [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cloud_shell).
There are also more general tutorials on installing helm on GKE from [google](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/helm/quickstart) and [medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/installing-helm-in-google-kubernetes-engine-7f07f43c536e).

Answer (score 0):

First you need basic connectivity to access your private cluster.
For example, SSH to a VM on a subnet that master-ipv4-cidr allows.

I had this basic connectivity but was still unable to install a helm chart as the install couldn't access services within the cluster.

I could only see this issue after adding verbosity to helm install and logging the output.

```
helm install -v10 my-chart  >log.txt 2>&1
```

With the [get-credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) command

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone us-central1-a private-cluster-0
```

Try adding the argument `--internal-ip`

This controls whether to use the internal IP address of the cluster endpoint. It made the difference for me.